# Computer freezes each time i run flutter app

Tags: flutter

Before today my flutter app was running just fine without my computer having a speed problem. But today while trying to run(in debug mode) my app, immediately it reaches the `gradle AssemblyDebug` stage my computer becomes slow and finally freezes totally, even `ctrl+alt del` doesn't work and all i can do is physically restart the computer.

- here is my flutter doctor summary:
  [image]
- I have an HP Folio 9480m with an intel core i5 2GHz processor, and 8GB of RAM

Comment: Looks like a memory leak. Did you change anything in your app?

Comment: That's what i thought but i tried creating a new app from android studio but still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this can be many things!please make sure your internet is not a problem.You can also try updating flutter to see if this solves the problem.
You can use the following commands to get out of the frozen state :

In mac/linux :

```
killall -9 dart
```

In windows:

```
taskkill /F /IM dart.exe
```

To update flutter SDK :

```
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: thanks  for the help , but in the frozen state i can't even move my mouse pointer, not to talk of opening cmd...any solution for that?

Comment: What version do you use?

Comment: I suggest you update your flutter :
`flutter clean`
`flutter channel stable`
`flutter upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

run the below command in terminal each time before you start running your app

```
flutter clean
```

This command will delete all the build cache files related to your app in your system.

**REASON:**

This is due to the build folder which has the previously built data.
clean it every time you run the app again from start
I faced this issue during my initial time of development in flutter & Now it is solved completely by using this command each time